# How to make the top QWidget modal?

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm developing an application in PyQT5 which has a `QWidget` object on the top. This application needs to be able to run in 'kiosk' mode, so my aim is to make that top `QWidget` modal and prevent any other running application of being focused.

The skeleton of the main class is below. Note that I'm calling the `setWindowModality()` method which in theory sets the behavior of the window to the chosen one:

```
class MyApp(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.setWindowModality(3)
```

My main method is the following:

```
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
MyApp()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

As per the `setWindowModality()` method [documentation](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qt.html#WindowModality-enum):

> Qt.NonModal   0   The window is not modal and does not block input to other windows.
>
> Qt.WindowModal    1   The window is modal to a single window
> hierarchy and blocks input to its parent window, all grandparent
> windows, and all siblings of its parent and grandparent windows.
>
> Qt.ApplicationModal   2   The window is modal to the application and
> blocks input to all windows.

The problem is that the window is not modal at all, I can switch to a different application (say a Web browser), which is exactly what I want to prevent. I've also tried 1, 2, 3 as values and they produce the same behavior.

I'm afraid this could be a design restriction in order to avoid apps block other apps, but I'm not sure of it and I'm unable to confirm it.

Am I missing something obvious here? In case the problem is the design restriction, is there a way to still simulate a modal window?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Modality is only with respect to current application. If application has only one open top level window, then there's no difference between application and window modal. This modality has no effect on other applications, so you are not able to achieve what you want with it, there's no simple "desktop modal" flag.

You can use Qt to make the window [full screen](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#fullScreen-prop), but you have to use other means to prevent user from accessing the desktop, or closing the app (often bound to ALT-F4 keyboard shortcut). If your platform is Windows, then I don't know how to do that, but I'm sure there's a way. Under X11 (used on Linux usually), the most straightforward way to do that is not have a desktop at all, simply by just running the app without desktop. Look up *nodm* package for an easy way to do this.

Comment: Using the full screen approach is a way, but that entails a lot of additional work, since it's not just the ALT+F4 combination to be blocked, but also others like ALT+TAB, the "menu" key (between CTRL and ALT)... Although doable, I think that will bring more problems than benefits. I'll check the `nodm` package, though.

Comment: Indeed, but all these shortcuts are handled by the desktop manager. No desktop manager -> no problem (at least as far as these shortcuts are concerned).